# how can I validate my registration form telephone input field with country code by geolocation

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a registration form where there is a input field for telephone number.
now, I want that when a client fill up the form the telephone input field will show the country code by default.

anyone is appreciated with example and thanks in advance

Comment: I do not understant if client fill with "Italy" and you put +39, or if client fill telephone field with +39 and you say "Italy"

Comment: assume that there is only one field and that is for only number input (telephone number).

Comment: geolocation sounds like a bad idea for this. Just because someone's computer is (or appears to be) located in Italy when they complete your form doesn't mean they have an italian-registered phone, or that their Italian-registered phone is the one they want to enter on your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://ipinfo.io, for this. It will give you the client IP, hostname, geolocation information (city, region, country, area code, zip code etc) and network owner. Here's a simple example that logs the city and country:

```js
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
  $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
  $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
  $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Client side IP geolocation using <a href="http://ipinfo.io">ipinfo.io</a></h3>

<hr/>
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="address"></div>
<hr/>Full response:
<pre id="details"></pre>
```

Comment: While this may work in a large number of cases, it's worth noting that obviously if they're using a VPN, or a corporate network whose gateway point is in a totally different location then you'll get complete junk as the result. For example my organisation's network frequently exits onto the public internet via an IP address which shows as being in a completely different city, and occasionally a different country. And users from all the organisation's geographically-dispersed offices use the same public IP. The exit point also varies from time to time.